# Sorting a List of class Objects by their int variable from least to greatest

Tags: java, list, sorting, object

Im trying to use insertion sort to sort classes in a List by their priority variable. Im just trying it with insertion sort, but any sorting method should work!
main class code:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    static List<Process> processList = new ArrayList<Process>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //hardcoded for example
        processList.add(new Process(3, "A"));
        processList.add(new Process(1, "B"));
        processList.add(new Process(2, "C"));
        
        The processes are current not ordered in the List by priority, so I call insertion sort
    }

    public static void InsertionSort()
    {
        System.out.println(processList.get(0).name);
        System.out.println(processList.get(1).name);
        System.out.println(processList.get(2).name);
        int n = processList.size(); 
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) 
        { 
            int key = processList.get(i).priority; 
            int j = i - 1; 

            /* Move elements of processList.get(0..i-1]).priority, that are 
               greater than key, to one position ahead 
               of their current position */
            while (j >= 0 && processList.get(j).priority > key)
            {
                processList.set(j + 1, processList.get(j));
                j = j - 1; 
            } 
            processList.set(j + 1, processList.get(i));
            System.out.println("Queue Sorted");
            System.out.println(processList.get(0).name);
            System.out.println(processList.get(1).name);
            System.out.println(processList.get(2).name);
            
        } 
}
```

and my Process class:

```
public class Process
{
    int priority;
    int name;
    public Process(int tempPriority, String tempName)
    {
        priority = tempPriority;
        name = tempName;bc
    }
}
```

currently the first 3 printlines in insertionSort are A, B, C in that order. (unordered)
the last 3 SHOULD be B, C, A (ordered from least to greatest)
But instead It's just A, A, A.
The problem is that A is overriding every other process in List, but im not sure how to fix it! I have a feeling it has to do with line

```
processList.set(j + 1, processList.get(j));
```

but I'm not sure how!
for more info on the insertion sort I used and edited: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Or just `processList.sort(comparing(Process::getPriority)`

Comment: Don't repost questions. Keep all the information in one question so people know what has already been suggested and tried.